# App Crashing on contact.save() when using ID - Apache Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Edit: I have tried this on multiple APIs and also an actual android device and it still crashes on save.

I'm developing a contact based app on android using Tools for Apache Cordova for Visual Studio and the cordova contacts plugin (v2.13). I can currently save and retrieve contacts but I cannot UPDATE a contact. I am using the genymotion emulator. and the **devices native contact list**.

You are supposed to be able to update a contact by passing in the a contact ID that already exists.

I have the contact object and all the fields are being populated but the app just crashes with no error messages when I try to save it.

I am aware this WAS an issue in contacts v1.3 and lower but it has been marked as resolved on their issues list.

[Contact Issue Resolution Documentation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-145)

Here is a screenshot of my object and also the full AngularJS code

[image: Object Image]

```js
droidSync.controller('managerController', function ($scope) {

    //Initialize model
    $scope.contact = {};

    // Create a new contact
    $scope.createContact = function () {
        // Contact Object
        contact = navigator.contacts.create();
        $scope.saveContact();
    };

    // Pick Contact from Device
    $scope.editContact = function () {
       contact = navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact){
            console.log(contact);

            //This only updates the text fields. It does not actually assign new values to the object
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.contact.firstName = contact.name.givenName;
                $scope.contact.lastName = contact.name.familyName;
                $scope.contact.mobileNo = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value;
                $scope.contact.homeNo = contact.phoneNumbers[1].value;
                $scope.contact.email = contact.emails[0].value;
                $scope.contact.id = contact.id;
            });
        })
    };

    // Delete Contact from Device
    $scope.deleteContact = function () {

        //Delete Function Here

    };

    $scope.saveContact = function () {

        var contact = navigator.contacts.create();

        if ($scope.contact.id !== "undefined") {
            contact.id = $scope.contact.id;
        }

        // Display Name and Email
        contact.displayName = $scope.contact.firstName;
        contact.nickname = $scope.contact.lastName;

        var emails = [];
        emails[0] = new ContactField('work', $scope.contact.email, true)
        contact.emails = emails;

        // Phone Numbers
        var phoneNumbers = [];
        phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('mobile', $scope.contact.mobileNo, true); // preferred number
        phoneNumbers[1] = new ContactField('home', $scope.contact.homeNo, false);
        contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;

        // Names
        var name = new ContactName();
        name.givenName = $scope.contact.firstName;
        name.familyName = $scope.contact.lastName;
        contact.name = name;

        // save to device
        contact.save();
    }
});

droidSync.controller('settingsController', function ($scope) {

});
```

Comment: without anything in log cat?

Comment: Im sorry do you mean the visual studio output window?

There was something like exited with error -1. Is there somewhere else I can find more detailed information?

Comment: did you try to test it in device debug mode? some Api simply not compatible with emulator, and some Apis are not compatible with some versions of Android.  command failed with exit code something usually happens in build time, try to clear cordova cache.

Comment: Ill try that this evening, thanks.

Comment: No luck, still crashes on a real device and any APIs I've tested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turns out it was the main scripts file being loaded in the wrong place... I had it referenced in the `<head>` tag and it needed to go in where the cordova references go at the end of the `<body>`

```html
<!-- DroidSync references -->
<!-- WHERE IT WAS -->
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

```html
<!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="app/scripts.js"></script> <!-- wHERE IT WAS SUPPOSED TO GO -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```